# String replace with with unescaped curly brace in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, postman

I'm trying to replace a value in a string with a double curly (used by postman for variable substitution), but every time I try to quote or escape the braces, I always get additional escaped quotes or double escaped braces, all of which break the substitution:

Original String:

```
"header": [{"key": "x-device-auth","value": "\"token\""}]

OriginalString.replace('token','{{token}}')
```

Result:

```
"header":[{"key":"x-device-auth","value":"\"{{token}}\""}]
```

If I search for `.replace('\"token\"','{{token}}')`, I don't get a match. The final string needs to be:

```
"header": [{"key": "x-device-auth","value": "{{token}}"}]
```

Comment: `('\"token\"', ...` -> `('"token"', ...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be looking for `token` with the escaped wrapping double quotes, since you also want to replace those.

```js
var originalString = '"header": [{"key": "x-device-auth","value": "\\"token\\""}]';
console.log(originalString);
console.log(originalString.replace('\\"token\\"','{{token}}'));

originalString = '"header": [{"key": "x-device-auth","value": "\"token\""}]';
console.log(originalString);
console.log(originalString.replace('"token"','{{token}}'));
```

I have added two cases, one with the original string actually containing backslashes (first originalstring definition). The second without. Choose the one, that best matches your actual input :-)

Comment: This only works because of the changed input... `"\\"token\\"" !== "\"token\""`

Comment: I assume, the input mentioned above is the actual string, not the js definition. That is why I added the first console log, to show the string is actually what OP is looking to transform. If you put OPs string in a JS string, you might as well have left out the backslashes, since they don't have any effect.

Comment: Now, you have the answer for both cases :-)

Comment: Thanks @ChristophHerold, as this was just a snippet of the full JSON object, I ended up doing `replace(/\\\"token\\\"/g,'{{token}}')` which is essentially the same as your first approach. The trick was understanding what the console was logging and what needed to be searched for.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see the input string is having proper escape characters applied. As you posted question in javascript tag, I tried below with javascript and its giving required results.

```
var str = "\"header\": [[{\"key\": \"x-device-auth\",\"value\": \"token\"}]";
  var res = str.replace('token','{{token}}');
```

Comment: This is exactly what led me to assume, that the input string is NOT the js representation, but the actual string, OP needs to replace stuff in.